# Angular - Changing dynamically style inside looped component

Tags: angular

I have a component with a basic button that I loop using *ngFor, inside that component is a function that adds class 'active' to a button which is currently 'clicked'.

The problem I have is the fact when I click another button the previous one doesn't change the color to normal one (style class stays there). Currently it works only when I click second time on the same button.

How can I achieve a situation to dynamically change colors of buttons (only one - active should have extra style class, rest should be normal)

here is my [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c1pjss?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: use ngClass to add class dynamically and set bool variable if it is true then change the color otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the clicked button outside of the component, and pass in if the button is active?

Something like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwuutm